# Iterate through JSON Object in Python

Tags: python, json

I want to iterate through JSON array in Python.
I have this JSON Array:

```
{
"test1": "Database",
"testInfo": {
    "memory": "0.1 % - Reserved: 31348 kb, Data/Stack: 10 kb",
    "params": { "tcp": " 0" },
    "test2": 100,
    "newarray": [{
        "name": "post",
        "owner": "post",
        "size": 6397},]
    }
}
```

How I can retrieve value of 
test1:
testinfo: and inside testinfo (memory..)
newarray

Comment: Json array, in what form? A fileobject, a string?

Comment: In JSON terms they call that an object. In Python terms, it is a dictionary. Only PHP calls that an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from json import loads

# This is a string, we need to convert it into a dictionary
json_string = '{
    "test1": "Database",
    "testInfo": {
    "memory": "0.1 % - Reserved: 31348 kb, Data/Stack: 10 kb",
    "params": { "tcp": " 0" },
    "test2": 100,
    "newarray": [{
        "name": "post",
        "owner": "post",
        "size": 6397},]
    }
}'

# This is done by converting the string into a dictionary
# and placing it in a "handle" or a "container", in short.. a variable called X
x = loads(json_string)

# Now you can work with `x` as if it is a regular Python dictionary.
print(x)
print(x['test1'])
print(x['testInfo']['memory'])

# To loop through your array called 'newarray' you simply do:
for obj in x['testInfo']['newarray']:
    print(obj)
```

Baisc python after you've used `loads` really.

Comment: Thank you very much! I do not understand how I can iterate through this array. x in your example is specific number, but what if I do not know the number of objects in json Array?

Comment: Just loop through `x`. Retrieve the value you need from each iteration.